# How to not mutate media variables when adding them to array after load. Closures?

Tags: javascript, arrays, closures

I have an array of image links and video links.  I am getting them from a `JSON` feed and adding them to my array one by one.  I want to make sure that they are fully loaded so I am using `onload` and `canplaythrough` event listeners for the images and videos respectively.  However, when I log the results of my array, it looks like to videos are never added and I am wondering if that is because I am waiting for the `canplaythrough` event to fire, in a `for` loop, which is changing the values of my `newMediaObject` (a constructor I made up).  I used a closure to prevent this in the first  half of my code, where the images are being loaded, but I am not sure how to implement the same method on the video portion. Do I need to begin the closure at Here is my code:

```
    for(i = entries.length -1; i >=0 i -=1){
    //Do I somehow start both closures here or do I make one in each part of the for loop (i.e. the video and image for loop)
    if (entries[k].type == 'image') {
        mediaObject.isVideo = false;
        mediaObject.url = entries[k]['ssMetaData']['images']['standard_resolution']['url'];
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = (function (entry) {
             //Here I am using a closure to prevent accessing the mutable variable
                return function () {
                    contentArrayNew.push(entry);
                    preLoadDone = true;
                }
        })(mediaObject);
        img.onerror = function () {
            console.log('error: bad image source');
        };
        img.src = mediaObject.url;
    } else if (entries[k].type == 'video') {
        var loadVideo = document.createElement('video'); //Temp video to preload without displaying
        mediaObject.isVideo = true;

        //I think the error comes here, when "canplaythrough" hasn't fired and so its properties are set to another item in the array's    

        mediaObject.url = entries[k]['ssMetaData']['videos']['standard_resolution']['url'];
        loadVideo.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function () {
            contentArrayNew.push(mediaObject);
                    preLoadDone = true;
                    imagesLoaded();
                }
            }
        }, false);
        loadVideo.src = mediaObject.url;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, whenever you create a callback that will be asynchronously executed and accesses a loop variable you will need a closure. The `canplaythrough` handler uses `mediaObject`, so it will need one there as well.

For simplicity, you might as well wrap the whole loop body in an IEFE to create a scope, instead of wrapping every single callback.